# jQuery: making a commentbox like FB

Tags: jquery

Hey. Facebook´s commentbox, how can that be done? 
So in a textarea there´s "comment..." and when you click it gets bigger, and a button appears, and then when you type more than the box size, the height of the box increases.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for:

- [Facebook like multi Toggle Comment Box with jQuery and PHP](http://www.9lessons.info/2009/05/facebook-like-multi-toggle-comment-box.html)

[image]

Comment: doesn't expand when you fill the box up.

Comment: As @Andre sad you could use `jquery-plugin-autoresize`

Answer (score 0):

1. on [.focus()](http://api.jquery.com/focus/), you [.fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) the button
2. the you use jQuery plugin [autoresize](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/jquery-plugin-autoresize/)

Comment: what you mean doesn't sounds like the comment box on FB. it's more like the shoutout box. ;)

Comment: but it does what you described in your question. What are you missing?